# Why the window is bigger than the image when display an image with opencv?

Tags: c, image, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV 2.4.2, and write a simple program to display an image.

The image is:

[image: logo]

And the code is:

## include "highgui.h"

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("logo.png");
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
    return 0;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

You can see there is a big grey border on the right. Why there it is, and how to fix it?

Comment: I think that is the smallest size possible since window must occupy 3 buttons on top.

Comment: You are right. When I change to a bigger image, it's fine. Please make an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the smallest window possible since window should occupy 3 buttons at the top. It will be OK if you enlarge the image.